# Как в Joomla совместить модули (в них самих пишется, что они совмещаются)?

Tags: joomla

Модули такие: News Show Pro GK4 и K2. Ставлю оба модуля, но в GK4 есть возможность выбора показывать новости только из стандартных категорий. Категории К2 не видит.

p.s. Версия Joomla 1.7. Может стоит 1.5 поставить, т.к. что К2 что ГК4 пишут, что вообще модуль под 1.5 и 2.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё нормально увидилось - ставил до этого версию не последнюю. Поставил последнюю, всё воркает нормально:)